# Navbar in HTML/CSS for mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, navbar

I am making a tech blog site and want to make it looking good on mobile too. I am wondering how you make all of the tabs (e.g. home, blog, about, contact) to be next to each other like this on desktop:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQhGT.png]

But on mobile I wan to have the three lines for a menu like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use Media Queries**.

Media queries allow you to modify your style depending on the media parameters. Here is an example of a CSS Media query that will be applied to the nav element when the width of the rendering viewport is less then 720px.

```
/* CSS outside media query will execute like normal. */
nav {
  background-color: black;
}

/* 
 * CSS inside the media query will be applied to the nav element 
 * when the viewport has a width less then 720px. The CSS here will
 * overwrite the CSS above.
 */
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  nav {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

For more information [read about media queries on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) or [read about media queries on Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Answer (score 0):

I typically use the input of type checkbox and label to achieve this. The general idea is that if the input is checked the label would show the label would be an X and it would be a hamburger button when unchecked.
Here is a sample https://jsfiddle.net/v0qjsh7p/.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="navigation__checkbox" id="navi">
<label for="navi" class="navigation__button">
  <span class="navigation__icon">&nbsp;</span>
</label>
<nav class="navigation__nav">
  <ul class="navigation__list">
    <li class="navigation__item">Home</li>
    <li class="navigation__item">Contact</li>
    <li class="navigation__item">About</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Visit the jsfiddle link for the CSS it is long but I added comments in the css

This is just focused on creating the button. You have the do the navigation yourself but it would give you the idea of using the checkbox system to hide and show navigation while also changing the button